# UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record:

Tags: apex, visualforce, error, locking

I am creating case through trigger,but i am getting the

UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record:

can anybody help me...

Comment: this existing questions might help you - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20921/can-anybody-explain-why-this-error-is-happening

Comment: i went through the link.. i just got the why it is happening.. how can i remove this error..can u pls help me what are the changes i should do in ....

Comment: Mind sharing your trigger code ?

Answer (score 2):

this could either be caused by conflicting DML operations in the various trigger execution or some recursive trigger execution.