# UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW

Tags: apex, after-trigger, locking

> Error while saving Quote Lines:SBQQ.ValidationException: [": execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 2 records: : []

Can anyone help me with the above error? I have tried using FOR UPDATE but it didn't work for me.

Do you guys have any alternative solutions?

Code Snippet

```
if(renewedSubscriptionids.size() > 0) {
for(Subscribed_Asset__c sa : [Select id, Subscription__c, Asset__c  From Subscribed_Asset__c Where Subscription__c in : renewedSubscriptionids AND Create_Quote_Line_Serial_Number__c = true]) {
    if(mapOfSubIdAndQuoteLine != null && mapOfSubIdAndQuoteLine.containsKey(sa.Subscription__c)){
        Quote_Line_Serial_Number__c qlsn = new Quote_Line_Serial_Number__c(Account__c = quoteIdAccountIdMap.get(mapOfSubIdAndQuoteLine.get(sa.Subscription__c).SBQQ__Quote__c), Asset__c = sa.Asset__c, SB_Quote_Line__c = mapOfSubIdAndQuoteLine.get(sa.Subscription__c).Id);
        qlsnToCreate.add(qlsn);
    }
}}if(qlsnToCreate.size() > 0){
insert qlsnToCreate;}
```

Thanks
Nirav

Comment: Could you post the code snippet that is throwing this error?

Comment: Refer the link - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20921/can-anybody-explain-the-unable-to-lock-row-error?rq=1

Comment: Hi Manish, thanks for the link, but in my case, I am not able to use the FOR UPDATE. I have to use other alternatives.