# System.DmlException: Upsert failed - UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to do an upsert using Database.Upsert() and getting this error:

**"caused by: System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 200; first error: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 13 records:"**

Normally, the code works fine, but on occasion I get the above error.

I know in SOQL statements you can use "FOR UPDATE", but I am doing Database.Upsert().  Is there anything that can be done to solve for this error?

Comment: Does https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20921/can-anybody-explain-the-unable-to-lock-row-error answer your question?

Comment: No @SachinHooda - That suggests using "FOR UPDATE" in the SOQL statement as I mentioned in my comment.  I am using Database.Upsert() and upserting a <List> of records.

Comment: My question is not a duplicate as it relates specifically to doing an UPSERT versus using a SOQL query